# How to dynamically inline SVGs in React/Next.js so I can apply direct styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm building a component that renders icons associated with a set of keywords. The icon will be different each time the component is used, so I could just us a direct path to the SVG file as the src of an image tag. However I need to style the `fill` of these SVGs with a color which is also a prop. I can't find a way to inline the SVG based on a variable.

I can loop my data and use this very simple component to render each icon. But not inlined so I cant apply any style:

```
export default function ExtraIcon({ name, color }) {
  return (
    <div className="extra-icon column is-2">
      <div>
        <Image
          src={`/images/icons/${name}.svg`}
          width={80}
          height={80}
          alt={name}
        />
      </div>
      {name}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've found a solution to this using [`@tanem/svg-injector`](https://github.com/tanem/svg-injector) but this works with a client side call after the component has rendered, and selects via DOM element ID which doesn't feel optimal.

```
export default function ExtraIcon({ name, color }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    SVGInjector(document.getElementById(`inject-${name}-svg`), {beforeEach(svg) {
      svg.setAttribute('fill', color)
    }});
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="extra-icon column is-2">
      <div
        id={`inject-${name}-svg`}
        data-src={`/images/icons/${IconsMap[name]}.svg`}
      ></div>
      <div className="extra-icon__name">{name}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I could possibly use `fs` to read the file and then `createElement`. That feels both convoluted and also against the Next.js approach. I also think I would need to do that in `getServerSideProps` and then pass down all the data of all the SVGs from the page component to this ExtraIcon component.

What am I missing? Or is this all too against the conventions of Next and I either live with client side injection or try to change the design?